# How to identify rows that belong to a cell in a table [r]

Tags: r, crosstab

Consider the following example,

```
>data(CO2)
>xtabs(~Plant+Type+Treatment,CO2)
, , Treatment = nonchilled

     Type
Plant Quebec Mississippi
  Qn1      7           0
  Qn2      7           0
  Qn3      7           0
  Qc1      0           0
  Qc3      0           0
  Qc2      0           0
  Mn3      0           7
  Mn2      0           7
  Mn1      0           7
  Mc2      0           0
  Mc3      0           0
  Mc1      0           0

, , Treatment = chilled

     Type
Plant Quebec Mississippi
  Qn1      0           0
  Qn2      0           0
  Qn3      0           0
  Qc1      7           0
  Qc3      7           0
  Qc2      7           0
  Mn3      0           0
  Mn2      0           0
  Mn1      0           0
  Mc2      0           7
  Mc3      0           7
  Mc1      0           7
```

I need to go through every non-zero cell in this table, *identify the row numbers of `CO2` that belong to the cell in consideration*, and do something with them. 
For example, I need to work out which 7 rows in `CO2` belong to Qn1, Quebec, and nonchilled, then do something with them, then move on to Qn2, Quebec and nonchilled etc.

I need a way to identify the row numbers of a dataset that belong to a cell.

Obviously, I can do `with(CO2, which(Treatment==xxx&Type==yyy&Plant==zzz))` and loop through the various factor levels. But this is not elegant at all, not to mention it will loop through empty cells in the table.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what exact output you want, but how about this?:

```
test <- xtabs(~Plant+Type+Treatment,CO2)
result <- data.frame(which(test != 0, arr.ind=TRUE))
result

#    Plant Type Treatment
#Qn1     1    1         1
#Qn2     2    1         1
#Qn3     3    1         1
#Mn3     7    2         1
# etc
```

If you want the names of the plant/type/treatment, you could then do:

```
result[] <- Map(function(x,y) y[x], result, dimnames(test))
result

#    Plant        Type  Treatment
#Qn1   Qn1      Quebec nonchilled
#Qn2   Qn2      Quebec nonchilled
#Qn3   Qn3      Quebec nonchilled
#Mn3   Mn3 Mississippi nonchilled
# etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why I didn't think of this before:

```
id=1:nrow(CO2)
solution=aggregate(id~Plant+Type+Treatment,CO2,c)
```

Welcome any other innovative solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `split` as well.  The result will be a "matrix" with "row.names" as the unique identifier

```
do.call(rbind,split(1:nrow(CO2),interaction(CO2[1:3]),drop=TRUE))
```